# How do I make value "long double" in TCL?

Tags: floating-point, tcl

How do I make value "long double" in TCL? C/C++ suffix "L" doesn't work:

```
% expr pow(2.0L,63)

invalid bareword "L"
in expression "pow(2.0_@_L,63)";
should be "$L" or "{L}" or "L(...)" or ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation, all floating point values in `expr` expressions are of the type `double`, so you can't.

Documentation: [expr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/expr.htm)

Comment: Unless you write some C code to do it for you, perhaps using critcl.